# CInternetSession::SetCookie Example

Tags: http, cookies, mfc, wininet

The MSDN documentation for CInternetSession::SetCookie defers to the [InternetSetCookie Win32 message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385107.aspx), but I had to keep digging to find an example in [Managing Cookies under WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385326(v=vs.85).aspx). I think example code for using this is lacking and would be useful to have.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have:

```
CInternetSession session;
CHttpConnection* connection=0;
try {
  INTERNET_PORT port = 80;
  CString server("mydomain.com");
  CString path("/cookie-test.cgi");
  CString cookieUrl("http://"+server+path);
  BOOL res = session.SetCookie((LPCSTR)cookieUrl,0,"my_cookie=Set My Cookie!");
  if(res == FALSE) {
    DWORD error GetLastError();
    // code to format error message
  }
  connection = session.GetHttpConnection(server,port);
  file = connection->OpenRequest(
    CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, //Action verb
    path //Object to perform action on
    ,0,1,0,0,INTERNET_FLAG_*); // pick your flags
  file->SendRequest();
  // Check status, read response, process
}
catch(CInternetException *e) {
  // report error
}
connection->Close();
file->Close();
delete file;
delete connection;
```

My cookie-test.cgi sees my_cookie with a value of "Set My Cookie!"